# Hide empty inputs in a dynamic form

Tags: javascript

When I am returning the dynamic form, I intend to hide the inputs when it returns an empty or null value.

For example, how can you retron the lines:

> Id = 1 NumCap = 1 Capitulo = teste

> Id = 2 NumCap =  Capitulo =

> Id = 3 NumCap = 2 Capitulo = teste1

When returning the form, when returning the line with Id = 2, hide the two inputs, because they come empty.

I return the form as follows:

```
success:function(data1){
  var linha1 = ``;
  for (var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) { 
    Id = data1[i][0];
    NumCap = data1[i][14];
    Capitulo = data1[i][15];
    
    linha1 += `<div class="teste1">
               <div class="form-group col-md-2 testeeeee">                      
                 <input type="text" class="form-control1 alinha" name="Capitul[]" value="${NumCap}">
                 <span class="form-highlight"></span>                       
                 <span class="form-bar"></span>                     
                 <label class="label3" for="Capitulo">Nº Capitulo</label>        
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4 testeeeee">                     
                  <input type="text" class="form-control1" name="Capitul1[]" value="${Capitulo}">
                  <span class="form-highlight"></span>                      
                  <span class="form-bar"></span>                        
                  <label class="label1" for="Capitulo">Capitulo</label>        
                </div>
                </div>
}
```

I am trying to put this code before starting the form return:

```
if(!NumCap && !Capitulo){
  $('.testeeeee').show();
}else{
  $('.testeeeee').hide();
}
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
success:function(data1){
  var linha1 = ``;
  Object.keys(data1).forEach(i=>{ 
    Id = data1[i][0];
    NumCap = data1[i][14];
    Capitulo = data1[i][15];
    if(!Id.length||!NumCap.length||!Capitulo.length){return;} //if any length of these values are 0, don't put them into linha1
    linha1 += `<div class="teste1">
           <div class="form-group col-md-2 testeeeee">                      
             <input type="text" class="form-control1 alinha" name="Capitul[]" value="${NumCap}">
             <span class="form-highlight"></span>                       
             <span class="form-bar"></span>                     
             <label class="label3" for="Capitulo">Nº Capitulo</label>        
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4 testeeeee">                     
              <input type="text" class="form-control1" name="Capitul1[]" value="${Capitulo}">
              <span class="form-highlight"></span>                      
              <span class="form-bar"></span>                        
              <label class="label1" for="Capitulo">Capitulo</label>        
            </div>
            </div>`
  })
}
```

Comment: This is more or less what I want, the problem is that after the inputs that I put in the question I have more inputs, and that way if these two inputs are empty it also hides the other inputs. I intended to just hide these two and show the other iputs according to that cycle

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to check blank value and hide the textbox

```
   if(jQuery(".testeeeee > .form-control1").length > 0){
    $(".testeeeee > .form-control1").each(function(){
    if($(this).val() == ''){
        $(this).hide();
    }else{
        console.log("TEXTBOX IS NOT EMPTY \t \n");
       $(this).show();
    }
    });
    }
```

let me know if this helps you.

Comment: I get this error "cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Comment: I used it but it is not working. Can you put it with my included code to understand how to apply your solution?